# Programming Phoenix - unable to access the register page

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

On my Programming Phoenix application, I've recently cleared my cookies, and now for some reason, it app won't let me access the "register" page (users/new).

It's giving me a "You must be logged in to access that page" error.

```
user_controller.ex

defmodule Rumbl.UserController do
  use Rumbl.Web, :controller
  plug :authenticate_user when action in [:index, :show]

  def index(conn, _params) do
    users = Repo.all(User)
    render conn, "index.html", users: users
  end

  def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    user = Repo.get(Rumbl.User, id)
    render conn, "show.html", user: user
  end

  alias Rumbl.User
  def new(conn, _params) do
    changeset = User.changeset(%User{})
    render conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset
  end
```

And my `auth.ex` code:

```
defmodule Rumbl.Auth do
  import Plug.Conn
  import Comeonin.Bcrypt, only: [checkpw: 2, dummy_checkpw: 0]
  import Phoenix.Controller
  alias Rumbl.Router.Helpers

  def init(opts) do
    Keyword.fetch!(opts, :repo)
  end

  def call(conn, repo) do
    user_id = get_session(conn, :user_id)
    user = user_id && repo.get(Rumbl.User, user_id)
    assign(conn, :current_user, user)
  end

  def login_by_username_and_pass(conn, username, given_pass, opts) do
    repo = Keyword.fetch!(opts, :repo)
    user = repo.get_by(Rumbl.User, username: username)

    cond do
      user && checkpw(given_pass, user.password_hash) ->
        {:ok, login(conn, user)}
      user ->
        {:error, :unauthorized, conn}
      true ->
        dummy_checkpw()
        {:error, :not_found, conn}
    end
  end

  def login(conn, user) do
    conn
    |> assign(:current_user, user)
    |> put_session(:user_id, user.id)
    |> configure_session(renew: true)
  end

  def logout(conn) do
    configure_session(conn, drop: true)
  end

  def authenticate_user(conn, _opts) do
    if conn.assigns.current_user do
      conn
    else
      conn
      |> put_flash(:error, "You must be logged in to access that page")
      |> redirect(to: Helpers.page_path(conn, :index))
      |> halt()
    end
  end
end
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
  scope "/", Rumbl do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

    get "/", PageController, :index
    get "/users/:id", UserController, :show
    resources "/users", UserController, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create]
    resources "/sessions", SessionController, only: [:new, :create, :delete]
    resources "/videos", VideoController
    get "/watch/:id", WatchController, :show

  end
```

My console looks like this:

```
[info] GET /users/new
[debug] Processing by Rumbl.UserController.show/2
  Parameters: %{"id" => "new"}
  Pipelines: [:browser]
```

And my browser pipeline:

```
  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
    plug Rumbl.Auth, repo: Rumbl.Repo
  end
```

Comment: Can you post your router code, to verify its hitting the correct controller function?

Comment: Just added it - seems to be hitting it correctly.

Comment: @clery00 can you also add the contents of the `:browser` pipeline in the router?

Comment: Too little details to properly debug this... Can you add your console trace when performing the request to the registration page?

Comment: @Dogbert pipeline added.